# Contour integral, Cauchy's Integral theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Define $$\oint_C f(z) \overline{dz}= \overline{\oint_C \overline{f(z)}dz}\;.$$ If $P(z)$ is a polynomial and $C$ denotes the circle $|z-a|=R$ (counter-clockwise), show that
$$\oint_C P(z) \overline{dz}=-2\pi iR^2P'(a)\;.$$

Is the problem have any thing to do with cauchy's integral formula? thank you.

Comment: Please take note of comments under your questions. I had commented under an earlier question of yours: "For displayed equations, the punctuation needs to be included within the double dollar signs (ideally offset by a `\;` space); otherwise it ends up on the following line, as you can see here. (Note that there's a preview in the edit area where you can check the formatting of your question before posting it.)"

Comment: @joriki: ok, got it!

Comment: There's also an edit link under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, although you couldn't see that from the definition you have. I recommend that you use $(z-a)(\bar z-\bar a)=R^2$ to get $d\bar z = -\dfrac{R^2}{(z-a)^2}\, dz$.